# Proper place to add listeners inside a custom Compound view

Tags: android, listener, android-custom-view

Where can i add the listeners so the are always added, no matters if the custom view is created from xml or if is inflated.

I try on `onFinishInflate` but is only called if the view is created from xml layout. There is no `OnViewCreated` or something like that where i can be sure that all inside views are created and an listener can be attached.

**Update:** Typical compound view

```
public class CustomView  extends RelativeLayout{

//called directy
public CustomView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    initializeViews(context);
}

private void initializeViews(final Context context) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

     inflater.inflate(R.layout.myview_layout, this);
}

//called when used inside xml layout
public ChatView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    initializeViews(context);
}
//idem
public ChatView(Context context,
                          AttributeSet attrs,
                          int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);

    initializeViews(context);
}
```

Comment: override `addView`

Comment: Do you extend a `ViewGroup` and inflate layout in your `compound views` `init()` function? You may set listeners after everything you need is inflated.

Comment: Yes, but if i understand correctly, depending from where the compound view is instantiated, different constructors are invoked. So, should be a place to override, where all inside views are already created no matter how it got there. I can always add the handlers after inflating inside the construtor, but that is not the point

Comment: most likely `addView(View child, int index, LayoutParams params)`, see `ViewGroup` sources for more info

Comment: It looks to be the best place, yet depends on adding. if i remove and add again i create a problem.

Comment: so override `removeView` or similar method

Comment: That's more or less what i am doing. Odd that there no proper place to hook, but seems to be the case.